# Debian 10, 2 nVidia cards GT 610 and GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: debian, nvidia, gpu

Windows user here

I have been using puTTy and smart putty and Git Bash to manage a few of my servers remotely, so far so good, I'm doing now is moving to the Linux community.

So, I have installed Debian 10 with GNOME desktop and managed to install the firmware and headers to make it work with nVidia GT 610.

It look ok, but since I have two video card I can't make both to work.

It shows 2 monitors connected to the 610, but also shows the other card as disconnected DVI-0 disconnected.

When trying to install using `apt install nvidia-drivers`, it shows the warning message, that the video card 610 won't be compatible that it requires some legacy drivers. After rebooting it goes back to the normal 610 video card.

Does any one know how to make this two video cards to work?

Right now only the 610 works.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Do you have both the standard and legacy NVidia drivers installed? And did you try the free drivers too?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, no, only the Legacy nvidia 390, when I try the standard I don't get anything working but a single monitor on a very low res, the legacy does work but only 2 monitors,the other 2, on the GTX 1050 Ti, are ON but not usable, all I see is the black screen with the X pointer... I also checked the nVidia Settings and all good, when I turn ON the Xinerama the gnome doesn't load at all, I had to use console to turn it off and everything when back again, only the 610 nvidia card...

Comment: Sounds frustrating. I'd give the free drivers a try.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to install the proprietary driver, seeing what package you install using the package manager.

If you look in the [dedicated Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Troubleshooting), and like you said, the GT610 needs the "legacy" driver while the GTX1050 needs the current one. Both cannot be used at the same time, the same goes for the proprietary driver and "Nouveau".

The only remaining solutions are:

- Installing the legacy driver to use the GT610

  ```
  # apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-glx
  ```
- Installing the current driver to use the GTX1050

  ```
  # apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-driver
  ```

Both are incompatible with each other.

Since the GT610 has been [released over 5 years ago while the GTX1050 was released less than 3 years ago](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GeForce-GT-610-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1050/m7736vs3650), not to mention all changes been made between the 2 architectures and the fact that the are both entry-level GPUs, you cannot expect anyone, and especially Nvidia, to put any effort to support this nowadays.

Therefore, the best you could do seems to be using the current driver with a usable GTX1050, though it depends on your use case. You might want to try the opensource "Nouveau" driver, but with [a major performance impact](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=nouveau-nvidia-eoy2018&num=1).

Comment: I did that, I uninstall the 390xx-driver and install the 410 driver, but! only the 610 video card was on... So what I did was to uninstall all together and re-install everything, but this time I went for the KDE, this time the driver 410 was auto-installed but only 610 was working, so I installed the 390xx driver and WOW! both cards were on! but can't share window apps between cards, Xinerama is a no go, X Server 0 = 610, X server 1 = 1050ti...

Comment: @Tanker Long story short, both GPU work with the package `nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver` and two `x11` servers?